# IIS PHP MySQL server stack unavailable under heavy load

Tags: mysql, iis-10

I am trying to build an IIS 10/PHP 7.2/MySQL 5.7 web server that is able to cope with very heavy traffic. It is a 48 core Xeon Platinum server with 188GB RAM. I am using the loader.io to perform load testing.

The load test navigates to a PHP page on the server which in turn performs a couple of MySQL queries (to make it more realistic).

When I run the loader.io load test, after approx 1500 users being active on the website I can see a lot of 500 and 503 errors in the IIS log and the test stops due to the high level of errors.

I have today switched to MySQL persistent connections to try and improve performance.

I have checked the PHP error log and there are no errors.

I have checked the Windows Server 2016 syslog and it says:

> Aborted connection to db: 'xxxx' user: 'xxxx' host: 'localhost' (Got
>   an error reading communication packets) For more information, see Help
>   and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.

This is my MySQL configuration:

```
max_connections=501
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=1G
thread_cache_size=100
key_buffer_size=2G
read_buffer_size=2G
read_rnd_buffer_size=2G
join_buffer_size=2G
sort_buffer_size=2G
```

This is my PHP configuration:

```
mysqli.max_persistent = 500
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
memory_limit = 128M
```

The resources never max out but the test still fails. Are there any tweaks I can change in my configuration or any other variables to test? Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider posting (on pastebin.com, if you can not post here), 
RAM  nnn TB/GB/MB on your Host server, indicate DEDICATED or SHARED w other apps? 
current complete my.cnf/ini and complete php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
#read_buffer_size=2G
#read_rnd_buffer_size=2G
#join_buffer_size=2G
#sort_buffer_size=2G
```

lead EACH of these 4 lines with # to cause DEFAULTS to be used.  Your use of these limits is extreme.  2 minutes with MySQLCalculator.com will illustrate the RAM footprint you are requesting is extreme.

Your configurations are limited to about 500 connections, why are you trying to overdrive the platform with 1500 in your testing?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, after following it and with a few additional tweaks I have now managed to get up to approx 5000 concurrent users without any errors at all. All users after 5000 receive errors though and the same error message appears in the event log as before.

During the load tests the RAM usage increased from the 10GB before the changes to 20GB still leaving 160GB spare.

php.ini - https://pastebin.com/kNRq71vW
my.ini - https://pastebin.com/3BehTMwS
Status - https://pastebin.com/RQ7Jjez3

The server is a dedicated VPS with the only notable apps running IIS and MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, but SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  after the stress load and before closing would be much more helpful to analyze than an 808 second uptime.  Could you run load test one more time and post to newer pastebin?   I would be grateful.

Comment: I have ran the tests again and here are the results, thank you again for your assistance
Before load tests - https://pastebin.com/JhzcMHxc
After 1 load test - https://pastebin.com/Tyi1CLTE
After 2 load tests - https://pastebin.com/WdvGRKXm
Results of the 3 data sets in a table - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4z7zd25cxgou4vc/Show%20Global%20Status%20Output.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions (after analyzing the 808 second uptime) for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld]

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 2000, v 5.7 5.1.5 CAP at 100 suggestion
innodb_io_capacity=1000  # from 200  unless you test for Random Write IOPS and get your own capacity
eq_range_index_dive_limit=32  # from 200, if U can not find in 32, 200 will not either
expire_logs_days=5  # from 0, so you have limited historical logs vs nothing
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to avoid overrun of page_cleaners volume
innodb_page_cleaners=64  # from 4 for auto limit = innodb_buffer_pool_instances
innodb_read_ahead_threshold=8  # from 56 will RD next extent/avoid wait
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 4  see dba.stackexchange Q 5666 9/12/11 Rolando
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 32  Rolando explains why - to use cores
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 4  turn it LOOSE SE 5666 explains
innodb_stats_sample_pages=32  # from 8 for more accurate cardinality
#max_allowed_packet=1G  # lead to use DEFAULT
```

when you need more than DEFAULT, in SESSION
SET @max_allowed_packet=nnnnn  up to 1G, which is the limit permitted in infile

```
max_join_size=1M  # from a huge # for a reasonable limit of rows
max_seeks_for_key=32  # from a huge # to limit OPTIMIZER endless search
max_write_lock_count=16  # from a huge # to allow RD after nn locks
sql_select_limit=1M  # from a huge # to limit ROWS selected
open_files_limit=50000  # from 502048 for more useful max
query_alloc_block_size=32K  # from 8192 to avoid RAM alloc frequency
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M keep your RAM for useful purpose, not using QC
query_cache_limit=1K  # from 1M to conserve RAM while QC not in use
query_cache_min_res_unit=512 # from 4096 will allow more results in QC
query_prealloc_size=32K  # from 8192 to avoid RAM alloc frequency
updatable_views_with_limit=NO  # from YES to reduce handler_external_lock
wait_timeout=3600  # from 28800 seconds, idle connections need to release rscrs, login will be required.
```

my thoughts this morning.  Would be happy to redo analysis with new GS and GV when posted in new pastebin's.

Comment: I have tried the config file and got similar results of 5000 users max:
Server variables - https://pastebin.com/6q8HGptx
Server status - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogtf3dj07bko6fi/Show%20Global%20Status%20Output%20v2.xlsx?dl=0
Latest my.ini file - https://pastebin.com/EjKqhkv6

It wouldn't let me start the service when sql_select_limit was in the config file so I set it using SET @sql_select_limit=1000000; in a different test and also set max_allowed_packet but was still the same result.

Comment: Great, do you have wall clock timing differential to run your tests?  From one run to another to another .......  to the last one?

Comment: We probably need to use =1000000 rather than =1M it sounds like for this version of MySQL.  Will try to have the redo on the analysis in 48 hours or less.